# Dynamically render Screen Flow from Extensions in Flexipage of Base package

Tags: managed-package, visual-workflow, isv, flexipages, managed-extension

I have a Managed Base Package `BASE` and multiple Extension Packages `EXT1`...`EXTn`. The Base Package contains a `CustomObject__c` and a Flexipage to edit the fields also packaged in `BASE`. The Extension packages model different flavours or types (Type__c field but NOT a native Salesforce `RecordType`) of the `CustomObject__c` by packaging additional fields and logic.

I am now looking for a way to have Extension Packages enhance the `BASE` Flexipage for `CustomObject__c` using Flow Screens (single Flows with multiple wizard-like screens).

When a user creates a `CustomObject` of `Type__c = EXT1` in the `BASE` Flexipage there should be a way to eighter embed (`LWC` component that dynamically embeds) OR load from a `QuickAction` (packaged in `BASE`) which loads in a modal the relevant Flow from the `EXT1` package.

[image]

If the user creates a `CustomObject__c` with `Type__c = EXT2` the Flow of `EXT2` should be used to edit `EXT2` fields.

How do I best start tackling that and what is your answers to:

1. Can I directly embed via LWC that renders a multiscreen Flow Screen wizard in the Flexipage depending on the CustomObject__c Type__c?
2. or should I use QuickActions renders a modal?
3. Is both not a good solution and there is a better way?

Comment: Does it have to bind to the Type__c field? I ask because packaged flows can now be "overridden" which means your base package could contain the object and base flow and however that flow is launched (embedded in flexipage, flow action, etc), then your extension package could simply override the base flow with its own flow. https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=release-notes.rn_automate_flow_builder_overrides.htm&language=en_US

Comment: Not a 100% sure what you mean with bind but in my case extension packages are not really optional extensions. The BASE functionality only works with 1 or many extensions installed that implement the specifics of their types. So overriding is interesting (please put it into your answer if you create one) but not a hard requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up with a solution that is composed of:

1. A `Custom Metadata Type` in Core that allows mapping Record Types to Flows
2. A `LWC` Component in Core which loads flow depending on Type and `CMDT` records
3. A single `Flexipage` in Core with a Tab that embeds this LWC
4. `QuickActions` in Core which also uses the same LWC.
5. A Flow in each Extension providing UI for the specific Type
6. A CMDT record in the Extensions for each Type

[image]

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

Aura components can be instantiated dynamically with `$A.createComponent('nameOfComponent')` so the component name can be delivered from the package resp. custom metadata around it. So basically you can instantiate specific components from each package within the same flexipage from the base package.
As Aura components can also launch Flows with `<lightning:flow>` this should be satisfying your requirement if I got it correctly.

btw: I heard a rumor whereas ISVs will be allowed soon to instantiate Lightning Web Components dynamically which is not possible by now, maybe you can check the partner portal for this.